# How to join many tables without duplicate result?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Hello all StackOverFlow families.
I need your help about sql query in mysql. I join four tables but result is duplicate row.

I have tried by using GROUP BY but not work.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT `tbl_leave`.`id`, `tbl_leave`.`staff_id`, `tbl_leave`.`type_id`, `tbl_leave`.`start_date`, `tbl_leave`.`end_date`, 
`tbl_leave`.`total_days`, `tbl_leave`.`reason`, `tbl_leave_type`.`type`, `tbl_employment`.`com_id` as `comid`, `tbl_staff`.`name`
FROM `tbl_leave` JOIN 
     `tbl_leave_type`
     ON `tbl_leave_type`.`id` = `tbl_leave`.`type_id` JOIN
     `tbl_employment`
     ON `tbl_employment`.`staff_id` = `tbl_leave`.`staff_id` JOIN     
     `tbl_staff`
     ON `tbl_staff`.`id` = `tbl_leave`.`staff_id`
```

You can look as picture: https://imgur.com/gallery/1Ewku

And this is relationship table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWPTj.jpg

The result I want like this : https://imgur.com/gallery/6NJpR

Thank for your valuable times for this question.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you spend too much time.

Comment: But stackoverflow no Table insert, So I decided to use image instead.

Comment: (You will soon learn that the `tbl_` prefix is more clutter than benefit.)

Comment: The 1st and 3rd links are broken.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
  SELECT distinct `tbl_leave`.`id`, `tbl_leave`.`staff_id`,    
 `tbl_leave`.`type_id`, `tbl_leave`.`start_date`, `tbl_leave`.`end_date`, 
 `tbl_leave`.`total_days`, `tbl_leave`.`reason`, `tbl_leave_type`.`type`,
`tbl_employment`.`com_id` as `comid`, `tbl_staff`.`name`
 FROM `tbl_leave` JOIN 
 `tbl_leave_type`
 ON `tbl_leave_type`.`id` = `tbl_leave`.`type_id` JOIN
 `tbl_employment`
 ON `tbl_employment`.`staff_id` = `tbl_leave`.`staff_id` JOIN     
 `tbl_staff`
 ON `tbl_staff`.`id` = `tbl_leave`.`staff_id`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this solution and let me know if is there any problem occur:

```
SELECT [Columns] From tbl_staff as staff
JOIN tbl_employment as emp on staff.id = = emp.staff_id 
JOIN tbl_leave as leave on staff.id = = leave.staff_id 
JOIN tbl_leave_type as ltype on leave.type_id = = ltype.id
```

Comment: Same query as OP's?(Just in another order.)

Comment: some time query order also matter